# Sorting assets based on name or id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a sorting select function to my app where a user can decide to sort assets based on name or id. In my render I added the select html. With the sortedAssets I am trying to act on the chosen decision. Can someone please help me with debugging the code as it is not working?

---

**Error console:**

```
/src/App.js
  Line 51:20:  'sortbyid' is not defined    no-undef   
  Line 60:27:  'sortbyname' is not defined  no-undef   
  Line 77:83:  'value' is not defined       no-undef
```

---

**Relevant part of App.js**

```
    sortedAssets(value){
      if(value === sortbyid){
        let sortbyassetid = this.state.assetsarr.sort((a,b) => {
        return a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1
      })
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        clickedassets:sortbyassetid
      })      
      } else if(value === sortbyname){
        let sortbyassetname = this.state.assetsarr.sort((a,b) => {
        return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1
      })
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          clickedassets:sortbyassetname
      })
      }
    } 
  
  render(){
  return (
          <div className="App">

            <label for="sorting">Sort assets by: </label>
            <select name="sorting" id="sorting" onSelect={() => this.sortedAssets(value)}>
              <option value="sortbyname">NAME</option>
              <option value="sortbyid">ID</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code, I put comments in your code where I changed it:

```js
//Put magic strings in constants
const SORT_BY_ID = 'SORT_BY_ID';
const SORT_BY_NAME = 'SORT_BY_NAME';
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    assetsarr: [
      { id: 2, name: 'A' },
      { id: 1, name: 'B' },
    ],
    clickedassets: [
      { id: 2, name: 'A' },
      { id: 1, name: 'B' },
    ],
  };
  sortedAssets(value) {
    //not using magic strings but constants
    if (value === SORT_BY_ID) {
      //sort mutates the array so will sort copy of assetsarr
      let sortbyassetid = [...this.state.assetsarr].sort(
        (a, b) => {
          //id is a number so can use a.id-b.id
          return a.id - b.id;
        }
      );
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        clickedassets: sortbyassetid,
      });
    } else if (value === SORT_BY_NAME) {
      //still not mutating state
      let sortbyassetname = [...this.state.assetsarr].sort(
        (a, b) => {
          //name is string, use localeCompare
          return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
        }
      );
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        clickedassets: sortbyassetname,
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* no reason to use id make select a child of label */}
        <label>
          Sort assets by:
          <select
            name="sorting"
            onChange={(e) =>
              //passing e.target.value
              this.sortedAssets(e.target.value)
            }
          >
            <option value={SORT_BY_NAME}>NAME</option>
            <option value={SORT_BY_ID}>ID</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state.clickedassets)}
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```